# C program game . Semaphores, shared memory not changing values

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, shared-memory

My program is to mock a whack a mole board

The moles are supposed to pop up and down randomly, but no more than four at a time. Why aren't my moles going back down??

I have a thread to continuously print the array of moles and a thread for each mole to control the popping up and down.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

void* printThread();
void* moleThread(void *);
long clockDiff_us(struct timespec tv1, struct timespec tv2);

int molesDisplayed = 0;
int maxDisplayed = 4;

pthread_mutex_t displayedSem;
int moles[9] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    pthread_t printer;
    pthread_t* worker;
    worker = malloc(9 * sizeof(pthread_t));

    int status;
    int molenum;

    //create mole threads
    for (molenum = 0; molenum < 9; molenum++)
    {
        int *id = malloc(sizeof(*id));
        *id = molenum;

        if ((status = pthread_create(&worker[molenum], NULL, moleThread, id))
                != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "thread create error %d: %s\n", status,
                    strerror(status));
            exit(1);
        }

    }

    //print thread
    if ((status = pthread_create(&printer, NULL, printThread, NULL)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread create error %d: %s\n", status,
                strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    sleep(100000000);
}

void* printThread()
{
    int i;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("printthread\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (moles[i] == 1)
            {
                printf("%d: 00\n", i);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d: --\n", i);
            }  //for i < 9 if moles[i] print oo else print --
        }
        printf("moles displayed %d\n", molesDisplayed);
        sleep(2);
    }

}

void * moleThread(void *id)
{
    int molenum = *((int *) id);
    struct timespec tm1, tm2;
    int sleeptime, awaketime;
    int us = 1000000;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm1);

    while (1)
    {

        sleeptime = us * (rand() % 9) + 1;
        awaketime = rand() % 9 + 1;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm2);

        if (moles[molenum] == 0)
        {
            if (clockDiff_us(tm2, tm1) > sleeptime)
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&displayedSem);
                if (molesDisplayed < maxDisplayed)
                {
                    molesDisplayed++;
                    moles[molenum] = 1;
                    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm1);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&displayedSem);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (moles[molenum] == 1)
        {
            if (clockDiff_us(tm2, tm1) > awaketime)
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&displayedSem);
                if (molesDisplayed > 0)
                {
                    molesDisplayed--;
                    moles[molenum] = 0;
                    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm1);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&displayedSem);
                }
            }
        }


long clockDiff_us(struct timespec tm2, struct timespec tm1){
       return  ((tm2.tv_sec - tm1.tv_sec)*1000000)+((tm2.tv_nsec - tm1.tv_nsec)/1000);
}
```

Comment: add -lpthread for compile

Comment: What about `long clockDiff_us(struct timespec tv1, struct timespec tv2);` ...?

Comment: And how are you compiling your code: post `gcc` command...

Comment: @LPs `gcc moles.c -lpthread -o moles` I added the function for the clock difference.. .my apologies

Comment: Your mutex unlock shouldn't be conditional. You always grab the mutex but you only release it in case the `if` statement below is executed. Move both `pthread_mutex_unlock` outside the `if` statements.

Comment: @Lundin yes! thanks! It seems to be displaying the wrong number of moles now in the print statement that says `"moles displayed %d"` Is that because of my mutex as well?

Comment: `molesDisplayed` is shared between several threads and you can't guarantee that access to it is atomic, so it should be protected by a mutex too. I'd put all those global variables into a single "mole struct" and protect any access to that struct with the mutex.

Comment: Not solving your concret problem, just a hint for programming: Actually, you don't need all that malloc stuff - `pthread_t worker[9];` would be sufficient in this case - the array will exist as long as the program runs. Same for your ids, simply have an array for: `int ids[9];`. Such style of programming prevents you from creating memory leaks (you never free the memory allocated - in the current case, not a matter, in other situations, it is).

Comment: And another one: instead of sleeping a very long time, you should rather consider a way to gracefully shut down your program. You could check for user input or install a signal handler, then cancel your threads or set a global flag variable such that your threads terminate. Join them afterwards and exit...

Comment: @Aconcagua that's extra coding, extra testing and extra debugging.  Gain, after all that work.... nil.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Replacing sleep calls with CPU effective wait functions isn't extra coding, it is correct coding. Each sleep call will possibly result in an OS context switch, meaning the real-time performance of such programs will be poor. If you need delays you should preferably use the timers provided by the OS. This program here only appears to be a hobby project so it likely doesn't matter, but in a real, professional project you'd probably not tolerate any sleep calls at all. Threads that aren't working should be waiting on a signal/event/mutex.

Comment: 'Each sleep call will possibly result in an OS context switch', LOL, sure, yes.  In this case, one change every 27.7 hours.  A while(1) round that would increase the loading to further extra loops every subsequent 27.7 hours.  Most would say that is an acceptable overload:)

Comment: Sure sleep calls can be misused, (eg. for polling inter-thread comms), same as so much in software.  It is, however, a stretch to say 'in a real, professional project you'd probably not tolerate any sleep calls at all'.  I use such calls often.  What do you do when a wait is required 10 functions down in a complex program?  Rewrite it as a state-machine so you can use a 'nice' timer, or make a sleep() call?   If the spec says 'always wait at least X secs before continuing', there is no point in raising events/semas just for an interval.  Just sleep() it - you'll feel better after:)

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic accesses to objects from multiple threads.